# Misaligned border around the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, cashapelayer

I am trying to create a border around a view. For this purpose I'm creating a layer with UIBezierPath the size of the view and making another layer with the stroke color. Then I assign the bezier layer to the stroke color layer and add it as a sub layer to the view.

Has anyone faced this before?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var rectangleView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bezierLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    bezierLayer.bounds = rectangleView.frame
    bezierLayer.position = rectangleView.center
    bezierLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: rectangleView.bounds).cgPath

    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.bounds = rectangleView.frame
    borderLayer.position = rectangleView.center
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 1

    borderLayer.path = bezierLayer.path

    rectangleView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
  }
}
```

[image: Device]

Here is the storyboard configuration if anyone's wondering that the constraints might be wrong:

[image: Storyboard]

[image: View debugger]

Comment: `layer.frame = rectangleView.bounds` should be enough. No need for `bounds` + `center` for both layers. And it should be done with that only. Also, could you print the size of `rectangleView` in `viewDidLoad()`, and in `didLayoutSubview()`? You might see what's wrong.

Comment: Suggestion: Why don't you do it as `rectangleView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0; rectangleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor` instead of creating a whole new sublayer?

Comment: Have you tried using the view hierarchy debugger? You should be able to click on your view during runtime and inspect the frame, border, etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: It's fine on the view debugger too, edit the question with the screenshot of that too @bkwebhero

Comment: @AhmadF I'm not doing that solution because I want custom rounded corners (on specific corners)

Comment: @AdnanZahid so do want do apply rounded corners on specific corners? If yes, would you mention which corners?

Comment: TopLeft and BottomLeft. I found the solution though, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, the trick was to put the border implementation in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    rectangleView.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
      guard let layer = $0 as? CAShapeLayer else { return }
      layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    let bezierLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    bezierLayer.frame = rectangleView.bounds
    bezierLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: rectangleView.bounds).cgPath

    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.frame = rectangleView.bounds
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 1

    borderLayer.path = bezierLayer.path

    rectangleView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
  }
```